How exactly do I prove the limit of a sequence using the $\epsilon$-$N$ method?
I understand how to use the $\epsilon$-$N$ method when proving the limit of a sequence. However, I feel as though it is just a big guessing game. Take this for instance;
The sequence below converges to 5 as n tends to $\infty$. But, in proving this, there is a lot I still find confusing
$$a_n = \frac{5n^2-1}{n^2+3}$$
$$|\frac{5n^2-1}{n^2+3}-5|<\epsilon , \forall n \ge N_\epsilon $$
$$\iff\frac{16}{n^2+3}<\epsilon, \forall n \ge N_\epsilon $$
Now, I don't understand how to proceed from here. I know I am to find $N_\epsilon$ that will satisfy the inequality but how exactly do I go about that? Do I just solve for $n$ or is there any kind of manipulation I should do to get the desired result?

Solving for $n$ would work. Once you have $N > 0$ such that $\frac{16}{N^2 + 3} = \varepsilon$, you can observe that $x \mapsto \frac{16}{x^2 + 3}$ is strictly decreasing for $x > 0$, so$$n > N \implies \frac{16}{n^2 + 3} < \frac{16}{N^2 + 3} = \varepsilon.$$There are heaps and heaps of other methods to go about it as well!

Hint: Consider "simplifing" the fraction, notice that $$\frac{16}{n^2+3}<\frac{16}{n^2}\leq\frac{16}{n}$$Then you need to find $N$, such that $\forall n\geq N,\frac{16}{n}<\epsilon$. Then can you continue from here?
Note: The second inequality holds for $n\geq1$. The general method is to simplify the fraction using different inequalities to some form you are familar with, such as $\frac{1}{n^2}$ or $\frac{1}{n}$.
Edit: I made some mistakes in the inequality, corrected it already.

Does this mean I have to make the fraction as big as possible? because $\frac{16}{n} >\frac{16}{n^2}>\frac{16}{n^2+3}$

Yes, but that is not the motivation behind, you need to make simple to deal with, in this case $\frac{16}{n}$ is easier to tackle with than $\frac{16}{n^2+3}$. It just happens to make it larger. However It is not necessary, for example if the fraction is $\frac{1}{n}$, then there is no need to do the process, because, you know, it is trivial.

But I wouldn't be wrong if I used $\frac{16}{n^2+3}$? Or does it only affect the condition ($n\ge N_\epsilon$)?

@esssystephen Both are fine, as long as you can find a suitable $N$.

It is always useful to write down the definition. Showing that $\lim \frac{5n^2-1}{n^2+3} = 5$ is equivalent to show that
$$
\forall_{\varepsilon > 0}\,\,\, \exists_{N \in \mathbb{N}}: n > N \Rightarrow \left|\frac{5n^2-1}{n^2+3} - 5 \right| < \varepsilon
$$
So, for any given $\varepsilon > 0$, you need to find an $N$ (depending on $\varepsilon$) such that $\left|\frac{5n^2-1}{n^2+3} - 5 \right| < \varepsilon$. In order to find $N$, we just need to work this last inequality:
$$
\left|\frac{5n^2-1}{n^2+3} - 5 \right| < \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow \frac{16}{n^2 +3}< \varepsilon \Leftarrow \frac{16}{n^2}< \varepsilon \Leftarrow n > \lceil 4/\sqrt{\varepsilon}\rceil.
$$
This completes the proof because, for any given $\varepsilon >0$, we are able to produce an $N$, given for instance by  $\lceil 4/\sqrt{\varepsilon}\rceil$, in the required conditions.
